# Upgrade PHP version on Fedora 8

Tags: php, fedora, yum

I have a Fedora 8 server I set up on Amazon EC2 back in late 2008.  I use to to run a few web applications.  I use yum to install applications such a PHP and MySQL.

I am currently running PHP version 5.2.6 and would like to upgrade to PHP 5.2.8 or higher.  When I run a 'yum update php', I see the following:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

* updates-newkey: kdeforge.unl.edu
* fedora: kdeforge.unl.edu
* updates: kdeforge.unl.edu

updates-newkey                                           | 2.3 kB     00:00

fedora                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00

updates                                                  | 2.6 kB     00:00

Setting up Update Process

No Packages marked for Update
```

So basically it is telling me that there are no updates to PHP.  I know that I could always update my Fedora to a newer version which has PHP 5.2.8 or higher, but I want to avoid that.

Any suggestions?  Is there a way I can update my yum repositories so yum uses a newer repository to make the update?  I would like to update PHP through yum.  If I have to I am open to compiling by source.  In that scenario what should I do?  Yum remove PHP and then compile by source? How do I compile php-devel?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

THANKS!!

Comment: Fedora 8 has not gotten security updates for over two years. I highly encourage you to reconsider and upgrade the whole distribution. If you'd like it to last a long time, consider CentOS or Ubuntu LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is that support for Fedora 8 ended quite a while ago.

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/LifeCycle

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life

"Fedora 8: 2009-01-07 ([EOL Announcement](https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-announce-list/2008-November/msg00021.html)) -- 426 days"

You aren't getting updates to anything, PHP included. No security updates either. **You need to upgrade your OS ASAP**.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Looks like upgrading is the consensus.  Had a follow up question.  In terms of "security" updates, how do I apply such things via the command line or yum?  Also Fedora releases have a N+2 lifecycle meaning most versions are no longer supported after 1 year.  That is very quick!  If Fedora typically run in production?  What do most people run in production?  Ubunto?  CentOS?

Comment: Fedora is not typically run in production for precisely this reason. CentOS is my distro of choice -- they'll be rolling out CentOS 5.6 soon, as well as 6.0. Ubunto LTS is another popular favorite. Security updates are applied/installed in the same manner as standard updates: "yum upgrade" and you're good. CentOS is supported for a minimum of 7 years from release, which is a huge improvement over Fedora's 1. I'm not sure what the lifespan on Ubuntu LTS is.

Comment: ... to clarify: no security updates are available for Fedora 8. :) You really need to upgrade, as I can guarantee you that Fedora 8 has multiple unpatched holes. Your distribution is likely as up to date as it is going to get.

Comment: Thanks Kyle!  I cracked open a RedBull and plan to spend my night upgrading my server.  One thing that I liked about Fedora was that yum repositories always had the latest stuff at least for the first 1-2 years.  How is yum for CentOS?  Are updates put in frequently?

Comment: No -- CentOS/RHEL have a different way of doing things. For example, CentOS 5.0 was released 2007-04-12. It shipped with BIND 9.3. I'm running CentOS 5.5 right now, and it still has BIND 9.3 -- but one that has had all relevant security patches backported and applied. They are just now, with 5.6, adding 9.7 as an option for BIND due the requirements for DNSSEC. Generally, the only updates to CentOS are security patches, no "major version upgrades" will ever occur. This leads to a VERY stable OS, but slow. If that doesn't work for you, you may want to investigate Ubuntu LTS.